# Creating draft via Google Gmail API

Tags: ruby, google-api, gmail, gmail-api, google-api-ruby-client

I am trying to create a draft message for a logged in user but keep getting the error `Missing draft message` when I run the below

```
require 'google/api_client'
client = Google::APIClient.new
client.authorization.client_id = ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID']
client.authorization.client_secret = ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET']
client.authorization.grant_type = 'refresh_token'
client.authorization.refresh_token = User.last.refresh_token
token = client.authorization.fetch_access_token!
gmail = client.discovered_api('gmail', 'v1')
params = { 'userId' => 'me', 'draft' => { 'message' => {'raw' => 'test email' } } }
# { 'userId' => 'me', 'message' => {'raw' => 'test email' } }
result = client.execute(api_method: gmail.users.drafts.create, parameters: params)
```

In addition I tried the commented out combination for params and still no luck.  Any ideas?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657004/gmail-api-with-net-client-library-missing-draft-message-400

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue when I was trying to do this for the first time as well.  The solution that I found was to not include the message information as part of the parameters, but rather pass that on in the :body_object as shown below.

```
@result = client.execute(
  :api_method => gmail.users.drafts.create,
  :parameters => {
    'userId' => "me"      
  },
  :body_object => {
    'message' => {
      'raw' =>  Base64.urlsafe_encode64('Test Email Message')
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: Correct though raw isn't just "Test Email Message" it should be something more like: "To: someguy@yahoo.com\r\nFrom: myaddress@gmail.com\r\nSubject: check out this cool site\r\n\r\nhere is the body, etc"

Answer (score 1):

`raw` in `message` is the full SMTP message.

- Either you set the content in `body_object`
- Or you set the full SMTP message including headers in `message`

eg:

```
params = { 'userId' => 'me', 'draft' => { 'message' => {'raw' => 'From: foo@example.com\nSubject:Ignore\n\ntest email' } } }
```