# Unable to create Draft using JavaScript GMAIL API

Tags: javascript, gmail-api

This question has been asked a few times but none of the answers has solved my problem.

I am trying to save a draft using Gmail API in JavaScript. But I get the following error.

```
 "message": "Missing draft message"
```

I know the reason is that I am unable to encode my arguments properly in RCF 2822 format although I have taken all the necessary measures. Following is my code:

```
        gapi.client.load('gmail', 'v1', function() {
          var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.drafts.create({
            'userId': "me",
            'draft': {
              'message': {
                'raw': btoa("From: me\r\nTo:" + "hello@person.com" + "\r\nSubject:"+ "subject" + "\r\n\r\n" + "message")
              }
            }
          });
          request.execute(function(data){
            console.log(data)
          });
        });
```

I have properly converted the draft email using **btoa** Can't see what I am missing.

Some of the answers on SC are related to Ruby. Almost none of the solutions work in my scenario. I have tried passing simple string as draft message still get the same issue.

Please guide me where I am wrong.

P.S I am successfully able to send email via Gmail API using almost the same code and encoding. But I can't save messages as drafts.

Comment: Did you check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25494664/creating-a-gmail-draft-with-recipients-through-gmail-api/25494682#25494682

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this issue, it looks like the API client changed the way it expects the payload. I had to remove the `draft` attribute to fix this :

```
      var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.drafts.create({
        userId: "me",
        message: {
            raw: ...)
          }
      }
```