# Missing draft message - javascript Gmail API - how to structure body of the request?

Tags: javascript, request, gmail, gmail-api

At the recent Google IO conference new Gmail APIs were announced. Client libraries are missing examples and documentation which is understandable given the short time that has gone by.

**UPDATE: It wasn't clear in the original question - I've already tried encoding the whole message as Base64 string.**

I'm trying to create a new draft message:

```
var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.drafts.create({
    'message' : {
      'raw' :  Base64.encode("To: someguy@example.com\r\nFrom: myself@example.com\r\nSubject: my subject\r\n\r\nBody goes here")
      // 'raw' : "VG86IHNvbWVndXlAZXhhbXBsZS5jb20KRnJvbTogbXlzZWxmQGV4YW1wbGUuY29tClN1YmplY3Q6IG15IHN1YmplY3QKCkJvZHkgZ29lcyBoZXJl"
      // 'raw' : "From: me@example.com\nTo:you@example.com\nSubject:Ignore\n\nTest message\n"

    }
});

request.execute(function(response) {

});
```

Can you please provide me with the **correct syntax** to do that?

*(Base64.encode is coming from http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html - tried using plain text, encoded version on the fly and hardcoded values from other question)*

---

Related questions:

- [Gmail api with .Net CLient library: Missing draft message [400]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657004/gmail-api-with-net-client-library-missing-draft-message-400)
- [Creating a Gmail Draft with Recipients through Gmail API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25494664/creating-a-gmail-draft-with-recipients-through-gmail-api)
- [Creating draft via Google Gmail API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25493213/creating-draft-via-google-gmail-api)

Handy links just for reference:

- Google Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/project?authuser=0
- Gmail API nodejs: https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/apis/gmail/v1.js
- Gmail API overview: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/overview
- Quickstart: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js
- Sample code from repo: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/source/browse/samples/simpleRequest.html

---

So I'm trying to find a solution in related questions addressing Ruby and C# by recreating JSON structure but I've reached the point that I need a Rubber Duck or Stack Overflow.

**Thank you in advance for providing a hint on how to structure the object passed to the API method.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a Gmail Draft with Recipients through Gmail API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25494664/creating-a-gmail-draft-with-recipients-through-gmail-api)

Answer (score 1):

While @rds answer is technically correct: "base64 encode complete message", the fully working answer is as follows... The correct structure of the request:

```
'draft': {
  'message': {
    'raw': base64EncodedEmail
  }
}
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/create *(scroll down and then choose JavaScript from dropdown menu)*

I was missing the essential **draft** property.

Comment: Close, but as of 11/17 correct format is:     'resource': { 'message': { 'raw': }}, not 'draft'

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is the same, [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25494682/94363) will be identical:

> 'raw' should contain the entire (RFC822) email, complete with body and headers.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is it's not just normal base64 encoding it's *WEB SAFE* (aka URL SAFE) base64 encoding.  It's similar except two characters in the alphabet are different to make sure the entire blob works well in URLs and javascript/json.